# Collect data into a CSV file using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm learning how to use [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

#### spider.py

```
import scrapy

class TestSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "test_spider"
  start_urls = ['https://example.html']

  def parse(self, response):
     for brickset in response.xpath('//div[@class="product-name"]'):
       yield {
         'name': brickset.xpath('h1/text()').extract_first(),
       }
```

I run this spider with command: `scrapy crawl test_spider -o test.csv`

This is working fine for `//div[@class="product-name"`, but I don't know how to add another CSS/XPath class in the same spider file

I'm trying this but it does't work

```
import scrapy

class TestSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "test_spider"
  start_urls = ['https://example.html']

  def parse(self, response):
     for test in response.xpath('//div[@class="product-name"]'):
       yield {
         'name': test.xpath('h1/text()').extract_first(),
       }

   def parse(self, response):
     for attempt in response.xpath('//div[@class="another-class"]'):
       yield {
         'color': attempt.xpath('h1/a/text()').extract_first(),
       }
```

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two `for` loops:

```
import scrapy

class TestSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "test_spider"
  start_urls = ['https://example.html']

  def parse(self, response):
     for brickset in response.xpath('//div[@class="product-name"]'):
       yield {
         'name': brickset.xpath('h1/text()').extract_first(),
       }
     for brickset in response.xpath('//div[@class="another-class"]'):
       yield {
         'name': brickset.xpath('h1/text()').extract_first(),
       }
```

Comment: It almost works but scraper saves to csv only first result CSS/XPATH //div[@class="product-name. Not for //div[@class="another-class"]

Comment: Are you sure your second XPaths are correct? Can you give me target URL?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I Get two correct result but scraper save one result into csv

Comment: But how do you know that you "get two correct result"?

Comment: I see this in terminal

Comment: 2018-05-20 13:25:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'test1': u'Top Ten tags'}
2018-05-20 13:25:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>
{'test2': u'\u201cThe world as we have...}
2018-05-20 13:25:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/>

Comment: test1 and test2 but scraper save only test1 into csv

Comment: If you see BOTH items in Scrapy debug log then something in your pipeline may filter them from saving into CSV.

Comment: Yes. You're right. This is work for .xml file (I have two result). Thanks. I don't understand why don't save for csv.

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse(self, response):
    product_name_lst = []

    # we will append all data to product_name_lst

    for test in response.xpath('//div[@class="product-name"]'):
        product_name_lst.append('name': test.xpath('h1/text()').extract_first())

    another_product_name_lst = []

    # we will append all data to another_product_name_lst

    for test in response.xpath('//div[@class="another-product-name"]'):
        another_product_name_lst.append('name': test.xpath('h1/text()').extract_first())

    # after that write to out.csv all the data you need from 
    # product_name_lst and another_prodct_name_lst   lists

    out_file = open('out.csv', 'a') # a meen append to file not rewrite file

    # and here you need to write in out.csv file 
    out.write(data) # data is what you need to write

    # and close the file
    out.close()
```

Comment: @pali112 what error ? this script don't work it is like template, you need to do something like this, don't copy paste

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try. And I run this somthing like: `scrapy runspider spider.py`?

Comment: `scrapy runspider spider_name`